# How to regex match file names with round brackets in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I match the file names in the following text in JavaScript? Mind the presence of round brackets in the first file name.

```
File 147034 (Screenshot (23.06.2021 16:55:00).png), File 147035 (Screenshot 23.06.2021 16:55:00.png)
```

I am pretty close with this regex pattern:

```regex
/(File \d*) ?(\((.+?)\))?/g
```

Comment: In this case you _want_ to be greedy I guess, so don't use `*?`/`+?`: `/File \d+ \((.*)\)/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match 1+ digits if they have to be there, and instead of an optional part for the parenthesis you can match either a comma or the end of the string.

With all the capture groups:

```
(File \d+) ?(\((.+?)\)(?:,|$))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/92SnPY/1)